# GDB option for 'python - c'

Tags: gdb

in this document (https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/28553.pdf), what is "r python -c" doing? Thanks.


[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r is running your program.

Arguments to run are program arguments to pass to your executable.

In this case arguments passed are calculated by running a python expression print "A"*264.
So this runs you program giving it a string consisting of 264 A characters as an argument.